# Tradingview pine script accessing external data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I would like create an indicator that would plot some data points from external source on the chart. For example, I have a file with dates and specific values and would like to mark these values on the chart.

Is there a way to achieve that in Pine script?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is now doable with the the `request.seed` function

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request.seed

Comment: This feature of is now suspended for new repositories based on https://github.com/tradingview-pine-seeds/docs